# Include Page Numbering into Table of Contents Hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I want to make the page number listed in table of contents also clickable.

Does anybody know how to do this?

[image: Clickable Table of Contents ref]

At the moment I use the following code to hyperlink my table of contents.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that I use for a clickable toc is:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}    %clickable ToC
\hypersetup{allcolors=black,linktocpage,linktoc=all}
```

[Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization) has a short summary of possibilities of the hyperref package. Especially:

```
linktoc | =none,section,page,all | defines which part of an entry in the table of contents is made into a link
```

Complete documentation can be found [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref).

Comment: The only thing of importance here seems to be the option `linktocpage`, correct?

Comment: linktoc did the trick thx

Comment: @Werner `linktocpage` activates links from page numbers but inihibits them from section names. Thus `linktoc=all` is the needed thing. The `linktocpage` is then overwritten by it anyhow.